# C# reference to Generic list (Equal to List<? extend object> in Java)

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 lists.
How can I declear a reference "objects" that can point to both car and plane?
I know in Java it is List<? extend object> objects, but is it possible in C#

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
List<Plane> planes = new List<Plane>();

List<object> objects;
objects = cars;
objects = planes;
```

Comment: This would be a source of bugs. `objects.Add(new Tank());` would compile and throw a runtime error.

Comment: Define a common interface and declare a List with this interface.

Answer (score 1):

From .NET 4.5 you can:

```
IReadOnlyList<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Car>();
```

(with `Vehicle` a base class of `Car`)

The [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) is covariant in `T` (`out T`), so you can use a base class/interface of the element of the real collection.

Clearly you can:

```
IReadOnlyList<object> vehicles = new List<Car>();
```

Being a `IReadOnlyList<>` you can't `.Add()` :-) But you can `vehicles.Count`, use the indexer `vehicles[0]`, ... and remember that it is the collection that is read-only, not its elements, so you can still `vehicles[0].BreakTheRearViewMirror()`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just cast one typed list to another. This is because `List<object>` isn't co-variant. (Imaging what would happen if you were able to call `Add("aaa")` after you casted the list...)

The best option you have is to make the last list co-variant, by not using `List<object>`, but a common interface. Not only for the generic type parameter, but for the list too.

```
IEnumerable<IVehicle> objects;
objects = cars;
objects = planes;
```

Then let `Car` and `Plane` implement that interface.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, but you can convert with minimal code using Cast like:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
List<Plane> planes = new List<Plane>();

List<object> objects;
objects = cars.Cast<object>().ToList();
objects = planes.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

But of course, it will create new instance instead of referencing.